# Updating existing debug app with different developers

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, apk, android-install-apk

I have trouble with updating the debug version of the app's apk:

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package [here our package] signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring

Two developers. Two PC's with same Android Studio versions (3.2.1). But when I try to install - have this, when the second developer make a debug apk with the same code (with git) it installs normally. 
If I make an apk - it's an error occurred via an update of a version of the second developer on a different device (tester).

What I've tried already:

- Restart Android Studio.
- Clean and Rebuild.
- Invalidate Caches and Restart.
- Build apk and installed from the device. ("Application doesn't install" error occurred during update)
- Increase versionCode.

The device is a Lenovo TB-X103F tablet on Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Did you try to increment version number?

Comment: uninstall the previous apk and install again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device

Comment: @VivekMishra, I need to update not just install a new version (for db in my case), it's obvious.

Comment: @user3344236, yes. Doesn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same debug keystore. Your colleagues' keystore will be at:

- Windows: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore`
- Linux / Mac: `~/.android/debug.keystore`

3 solutions are below in descending order of correctness:

1. In the long term, this should be configured *inside* your project, so that anyone with the project can sign the debug builds. This is done by configuring your `build.gradle` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044728/608312).
2. You can also set your signing config inside Android Studio, so you are not reliant on copying his file in the future. [Here is how to set it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992232/608312).
3. You could also just replace your debug keystore in that location with your colleagues, so you are using the same config.

Comment: Strange thing but it works! "You could also just replace your debug keystore in that location with your colleagues, so you are using the same config"

Answer (score 1):

Different keystore files cause this warning. For the exact solution;

-Create your own keystore files for each build types.

-Define buildTypes and SigningConfigs in app level gradle file
   like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias '******'
        keyPassword '******'
        storeFile file('...\\release.jks')
        storePassword '******'
    }

    debug {
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword '******'
        storeFile file('...\\debug.jks')
        storePassword '******'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
        }
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

**NOTE!!! You can move debug keystore file into project folder(app folder will be a good choice). So both developers have the same keystore easily.**

Comment: Thank You for your answer and time. But in my case helped answer of @JakeSteam.